# Code to display all successful purchases in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the total number of purchases made on my site to my site users; Previously, I wrote the code that displayed the total number of products published on my site, and now I want the code to display the total number of successful purchases from my site to the user.

The code I wrote to display the number of products on my site is as follows:

```
function product_count_shortcode() {
  $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'product' );
  return $count_posts->publish;
}
add_shortcode( 'product_counthalsho', 'product_count_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will basically have to show the number of orders that have the status completed. Just create a function that will query the order post_type and with the status completed.

You can simply use [get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and use the php function [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the check how many results you have, or use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) that already has a property in the return object that tells you how many orders you have with that status.

Later Edit:

```
function mrc_total_completed_orders() {
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'completed',

);
$orders = get_posts( $args );

return count( $orders ); }
```

Or you can use the WC_Order_Query

```
function mrc_mrc_total_completed_Orders() {
$query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'limit' => 99999,
    'status'        => array( 'completed' ),
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$orders = $query->get_orders();

return count( $orders ); }
```

Also some documentation [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#usage)

Note that I haven't tested these solutions, but its enough to get you started :)

Usage:

```
echo mrc_mrc_total_completed_Orders();
```

Comment: Hello. Can you write the complete code for me? I just want to show the total number of completed orders to users.

Comment: I updated the previous answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Many thanks. I had already written and tried the first code and it didn't work, but the second code that you wrote using WC_Query worked fine.